# header de activity Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

Actualmente mi pantalla se ve asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero donde esta la hora no esta tomando color de background, como podria establecerle un color a este header.

Mi pregunta es :

- Como puedo setearle un color dinamicamente?
- Como se llama este lugar de la app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

debes esconder el navigationBar en esta vista o de lo contrario ponerlo transparente.

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
  self.navigationController.navigationBar.isHidden = true
```

y luego en volverla a mostrar al salir de esta vista.

```
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
}
```

Comment: Gracias kjoe estas en todos lados!